# C# XML not correctly validating against Schema in XmlReaderSettings

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd, schema

I searched and did not find any questions addressing this problem.

I am attempting to validate various XML against a schema and ***it seems to be validating ALL well-formed XML, instead of just XML that conforms to the schema***. I have posted the code I am using, the Schema, a sample valid XML and a sample invalid XML.

I have been struggling with this for awhile. I am in the dark on most of this. I've had to learn how to write an XSD, write the XSD, then learn how to parse XML in C#. None of which I have ever done before. I have used many tutorials and the microsoft website to come up with the following. I *think* this should work, but it doesn't.

What am I doing wrong?

```
private bool ValidateXmlAgainstSchema(string sourceXml, string schemaUri)
{
    bool validated = false;
    try
    {
        //  REF:
        //  This should create a SCHEMA-VALIDATING XMLREADER
        //  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5aahf2a(v=vs.110).aspx

        XmlReaderSettings xmlSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        xmlSettings.Schemas.Add("MySchema.xsd", schemaUri);
        xmlSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        xmlSettings.ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.None;
        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(sourceXml), xmlSettings);

        //  parse the input (not sure this is needed)
        while (xmlReader.Read()) ;

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(xmlReader);

        validated = true;
    }
    catch (XmlException e)
    {
        //  load or parse error in the XML
        validated = false;
    }
    catch (XmlSchemaValidationException e)
    {
        //  Validation failure in XML
        validated = false;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        validated = false;
    }
    return validated;
}
```

The XSD / Schema. The intent is to accept XML that contains either an Incident or a PersonOfInterest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="MySchema.xsd"
    xmlns="MySchema.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
>
  <xs:element name="Incident" type="IncidentType"/>
  <xs:element name="PersonOfInterest" type="PersonOfInterestType"/>

  <xs:complexType name="IncidentType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="PersonOfInterest" type="PersonOfInterestType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="PersonOfInterestType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Here is a sample of *valid* XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

  <Incident
      xmlns="MySchema.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com MySchema.xsd"
  >
    <Description>something happened</Description>
    <PersonOfInterest>
        <Name>Joe</Name>
    </PersonOfInterest>
    <PersonOfInterest>
        <Name>Sue</Name>
    </PersonOfInterest>
  </Incident>
```

This is a sample of well-formed *invalid* XML which should throw an exception (I thought), but when I try it, the code returns true, indicating it is valid against the schema.

```
<ghost>Boo</ghost>
```

Comment: If you miss to add the schemaLocation to any well-formed invalid xml as in the above snippet it would not work. Did you try this with Visual Studio IDE to validate the xml with schema before parsing it in your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your `<ghost>Boo</ghost>` validates is that the parser cannot find any schema matching the xml. If there is no schema then the parser assumed validity, providing the xml is well-formed. It's counter-intuitive I know, and will probably differ based on parser implementation.

This notwithstanding, there are several problems with your code:

**Two Root Elements**

This is a big no-no in xsd - you can only have a single root element. Some parsers will actually throw an exception, others tolerate it but will only use the first root element (in your case *Incident*) for any subsequent validation.

**Use of schemaLocation attribute**

This should take the value `(namespace) (URI)` where the namespace is the targetNamespace of the schema and the URI is the location of the schema. In your case you appear to be using the schema file name as your target namespace. Additionally, looking at your code, you are loading the schema into your xml reader so you don't actually need the schemaLocation attribute at all. This is an optional attribute and some parsers completely ignore it.

I would suggest the following changes:

```
<xs:schema
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://MyMoreMeaningfulNamespace"
    xmlns="http://MyMoreMeaningfulNamespace"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
>
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Incident" type="IncidentType"/>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="PersonOfInterest" type="PersonOfInterestType"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="IncidentType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="PersonOfInterest" type="PersonOfInterestType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="PersonOfInterestType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Which validates this instance

```
<Root xmlns="http://MyMoreMeaningfulNamespace">
  <Incident>
    <Description>something happened</Description>
    <PersonOfInterest>
      <Name>Joe</Name>
    </PersonOfInterest>
    <PersonOfInterest>
      <Name>Sue</Name>
    </PersonOfInterest>
  </Incident>

  <Incident>
    ...
  </Incident>

  <PersonOfInterest>
    <Name>Manny</Name>
  </PersonOfInterest>

  <PersonOfInterest>
    ...
  </PersonOfInterest> 

</Root>
```

Comment: Terrific! Thank you for that excellent explanation! Does the target namespace have to be a website? Can it jut be my company's name?

Comment: I just re-read your question - in order to validate that the xml contains an Incident OR a Person, just change the xs:sequence to an xs:choice in the root complex type. This will enforce "either/or" semantics

Comment: Target namespace is just a string. Can be anything but by convention it's a URI. It doesn't need to resolve to an actual resource. It's like namespaces in C# - prevents name collisions.

Comment: Yep, I caught the xs:choice change. Not a big deal, and I appreciate you pointing that out. Also, thank you for the clarification on the namespace. Wish I could +1 more. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add that you can enable warnings:

```
xmlSettings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
```

so you can get a message for an entry like `<ghost>Boo</ghost>`